# Angular best practice for using TestBed.CompileComponents().then()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

I have a test bed set up to verify that my module has been defined.

```
describe('MyModule', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MyModule]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(MyModule).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

My code style tool SonarQube is requesting that I add a `.then()` statement to the `.compileComponents()` line as the promise returned is unused.

Is it better to leave it as is and ignore the style tool or to add an empty statement like `.then(() => { /* empty */ })`?

I'm leaning towards ignoring the tool but would like to know which way better suits the published Angular style documentation.

Comment: I get these warnings in WebStorm/TSLint. It's not a technical issue, because a promise will still resolve if no one calls `then()`. The warning is trying to tell the developer that they didn't handle a yielded result and is likely a mistake, but in this case it is not a mistake. So you can ignore it or suppress it by using a comment to disable it. Calling `.then()` is just sympatics to suppress the warning.

Comment: So do you suggest adding an ignore statement?

Comment: If you are using Sonar, and you want Sonar not to report the issue then add an ignore or reconfigure Sonar. If you're going to share the source code with other people who won't be using Sonar, then just ignore it. Adding a `.then()` can easily be deleted by another developer who thinks it shouldn't be there. It's all the same as debating tabs vs spaces for indents. Make your own decision...

Comment: It is a good practice to terminate everything in JavaScript, because you might run into unexpected situations when for example a function returns `Promise` instead of `void` or not returning `Promise` when expected. Rules like that in SQ and tslint are there for a reason and you should follow them.

Comment: Don't forget that you can simply `return` the entire method chain if you don't like an empty `then` and you also dislike the linting errors

`beforeEach(async(() => {
        return TestBed.configureTestingModule({ // <--- Notice the return
            imports: [MyModule]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code looks broken, it should be:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MyModule]
    }).compileComponents();
});
```

That should not trigger SQ anymore. But if you're not using async, then you can use empty `.then()`, this is a correct way.

Comment: Just tested, it compiles and the tests pass in both your version and mine.

Comment: Do you have a function called `async` defined anywhere?

Comment: ahh yea i was importing async from '@angular/core/testing' thanks